# Ajax button clicked but does not delete image from database in boostrap modal

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, pdo, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal where where the user can delete image by ajax.
But when i click on the modal delete the ajax does not button doesnot do anything.

My php code-

```
                                                         <?php

                                                                include_once '../../php/connection.php';

                                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM img_info LEFT JOIN estate_infos ON img_info.estate_infos_id = estate_infos.id
                                                                                                                                where img_info.estate_infos_id = $mdoalid";
                                                                $stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
                                                                $stmt->execute();
                                                                $count = $stmt->rowCount();
                                                                $datas = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                                                foreach ($datas as $key => $data) 
                                                                {
                                                                    $pic = $data['image'];
                                                                    $a = $data['img_id'];

                                                                ?>

           <img src="../<?php echo $pic ?>" width="360"
                                                                height="150">
                                                            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"
                                                                data-imgid="<?php echo $data['img_id']; ?>">
                                                                <i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x"
                                                                    aria-hidden="true" style="color:red"></i>
                                                            </a>

                                                            <?php echo $a ?>



                                                            <?php
                                                                }
                                                            ?>
```

My modal -

```
<!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="delimglabel"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="delimglabel">Delete Image</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">Are you sure you
                                want to delete the image?</div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="delbtn btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-white btn-danger"
                                    data-delete-imgid="<?php echo $data['img_id']; ?>">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My ajax code-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { 
        var imageId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('imgid'); 
        $(e.currentTarget).find('.delbtn').attr('data-delete-imgid',
            imageId); 
    });
    $(".delbtn").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "image-del.php",
            data: {
                delbtn: $(this).data('delete-imgid')
            }
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Image Deleted !');
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert('Image NOT Deleted !')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My mysql Code-

```
<?php 
include_once 'connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['delbtn'])) {
$img_id = $_POST['img_id'];   
$sql = "DELETE FROM img_info WHERE img_id=:img_id";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(':img_id', $img_id);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

When i click on the delete icon the modal pops up and after that when i click delete button it doesnot do anything.

[Screenshot of the modal after clicked delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to8TC.png)

Image doesnot deleted probelm-
[Image not deleted ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtaAZ.png)

Plese help in fixing the problem.
-Thank you

Comment: what do you see in browser console?

Comment: I believe you should change this line `$img_id = $_POST['img_id'];` to `$img_id = $_POST['delbtn'];` in your PHP code (`My mysql Code`). And additionally missing comma before `success: function(response)` in your Ajax code

Comment: @tech2017 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. The problem is in this line of ajax->  success: function(response) {
                    alert('Image Deleted !');
                },

Comment: @rceman i did that still same problem

Comment: Add a comma before `success: function(response)` in your Ajax

Comment: @rceman oh the error gone when i placed the comma  but now shows "image not deleted" which means ajax is working but going to error part.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of image not deleted alert

Comment: try console.log(response); in error block. What do you see?

Comment: it was a 404 error of the url in ajax and i put the right path and it got deleted . Thank you very much @tech2017 and rceman

Comment: Great! You're welcome